# What is the part of speech/ function of "John asked him?"

Tags: parts-of-speech, grammatical-roles

What is the part of speech/ function of "John asked him" below?

> Bob revealed the deep question John asked him.

Comment: I'd expect the undeleted version to be 'Bob revealed the deep question that John had asked him.'

Comment: [that] John asked him.=relative clause.

Comment: Yes, an integrated (defining) relative clause modifying the nominal "deep question".